# How to check for valid URL while catching connection adapter errors?

Tags: python

I have an Excel file containing a large list of URL's for some PDF files. I am using a Try block to check which URLs are active, and which are not.

```
df = pd.read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
print(df['Pdf_URL'][0:5])

try:
    response = requests.get(df['Pdf_URL'])
    print("URL exists")
except requests.ConnectionError as exception:
    print("URL does not exist")
```

When I try to run through the whole list like this, I get the following error:

```
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0'
```

What I tried:
Instead of running through the entire list, I tried to go through one URL at a time.

```
try:
    response = requests.get(df['Pdf_URL'][1])
    print("URL exists")
except requests.ConnectionError as exception:
    print("URL does not exist")
```

I found out that there are some URLs in the list that do not start with `http`. For example one of the links in the list start with `html://`.

This will give me the connection adapters error like the one above.

What can I add to my block in order to prevent these errors from stopping the program while I check the URL list?

Answer (score 0):

You can just handle the respective exception within the loop:

```py
for url in df['Pdf_URL']:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except requests.ConnectionError as exception:
        print("URL does not exist")
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
        print("Invalid URL:", url)
    else:    
        print("URL exists")
```